# Can I extract a certificate private key from the windows certificate store in a disk image?

Tags: windows-7, ssl, certificate

After re-installing Windows 7 I notice that I seem to have failed to export the private key for one of my client certificates (for Internet Explorer use).

When viewing the certificate in IE, it happily claims "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate" but when I go into options and try to do an export it says "The associated private key cannot be found".

I still have a disk image of the hard drive of the old Windows installation, and it would be possible for me to write this image to a disk and boot up the old installation to be able to re-export the certificate (this time including the private key) but it would be really convenient if there was a way to access/extract the key and/or certificate data directly from the file system instead.

Googling indicates that the keys are stored in  AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates\ and those files where copied from the old install to the new, but it seems the private key is not stored in those files.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/304962/where-is-an-ssl-private-key-stored

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/631084/windows-certificate-manager-restore-private-key-somehow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883438/where-is-private-key-when-using-ssl-stored

Comment: As far as I could understand from the two first posts, I have already copied the relevant files to the new computer and the private keys does not seem to be in there. the third post seems irrelevant for my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was not resolved. I acquired a new certificate from the issuer instead. The other questions linked in the comments did not help.